# Story where people are tested for what career they are most suited for, main character tested at a high level for magic

Tags: story-identification, magic

A normal human white girl considers herself a normal, knows about the magic class/society. On testing day all people are tested to find out what you are best at for their life career.  She tested at a high level for magic; magic users live in a separate society. She's now attending a training school to learn about using magic and how to live, and the rules of the society that uses magic.  Most are in/or allied to families; they are arrogant.

As she's learning to navigate this society, she makes friend's and enemies, she stumbles on a mystery involving death and the resurrection of an evil entity, headed by her schools headmaster. This causes chaos in the magic society.

Comment: You've provided a few details, however we could really use some more. Please take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) and see if you can [edit] in any more details.

Comment: Basic plot is similar to [The Magisterium Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Magisterium_Series) by Holly Black & Cassandra Clare.  However, the main character is male and I doubt they used Wattpad since they are both established authors.

Answer (score 2):

On Wattpad, there is a story by NightfallShipper titled *[Level 5](https://a.wattpad.com/story/138938898-level-5)*, which has a plot similar to what you are describing above.

> The Level 5 Program gives students the chance to enter in a Special School for gifted students charge free! All that's required is a test taken near the end of the summer, on August 20th. If you are able to get a 95% or above, you are guaranteed a spot in the Special School.

The "Special School" is government run, and involves a serum given to children that lets them use magic. The protagonist, Cassie, is one of the daughters of a couple that formally worked with the government, and at the beginning of the story, it's revealed that Cassie inherited some of their powers without being injected with the serum.